# Маркировка запросов к БД в YII2 ActiveRecord

Tags: база-данных, yii2, activerecord

Есть большое приложение, разделенное на модули, запросы в БД летят из разных модулей. Можно ли как-то вставлять комментарий перед запросом, чтобы пометить запрос и понять потом из логов СУБД из какого модуля он был сделан?

Comment: Может я вас не так понял, но в дебаг панели в разделе "DB" ведь указывается в каких файлах вызывается тот или иной запрос. https://prnt.sc/f8g0jj

Comment: Какое-то задание выполняется ночью, а может обращение по АПИ, просто проект большой, не известно где такой запрос формируется, это нужно выяснить